# Where is the value of the "app_store" in the Firebase come from?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

From the [Google Firebase official doc](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en), the `user_dim.app_info.app_store` is defined as

> The store which installed this app.

And after checked my data, I've gotten some values of this key, like

> ```
> com.android.vending
> manual_install
> cm.aptoide.pt
> com.baidu.androidstore
> test
> com.google.android.feedback
> com.dragon.android.mobomarket
> co⁭.android.vending
> com.miui.cloudbackup
> com.amazon.venezia
> ```

Now I have a question: where the Firebase SDK get these values from?

Comment: Are you sure for baidu it returns "com.baidu.androidstore" ?. Because when am installing Baidu Store in Xiomi device, Baidu package name is retrieved as "com.miui.packageinstaller"  and not "com.baidu.androidstore"

Comment: @Anand I've not talk anything about *baidu* in my question. The `com.baidu.androidstore` is just my found in my *firebase* log data. Thanks.

Comment: @Anand And from your comment, it seems you have not understand what the `app_store` means.

Comment: If you found com.baidu.androidstore in log data, means you have some package installed. app_store defines from which store app. is installed like Play Store, Baidu etc.

Comment: @Anand These data are not from one device, but from my app's users. So there is `baidu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android the package of the app that installed the current app is reported by the [getInstallerPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)) method provided by the [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). When the app is installed by Google Play Store the package is reported as `"com.android.vending"` though Firebase Analytis will replace that with empty string to save disk and network bandwidth. Sideloaded apps will be reported as `manual_install`.

On iOS the only possible store iTunes is reported as emptry app_store value. Sideloaded apps are reported as `manual_install` as on Android.

Comment: What does "sideload" mean?

Comment: It means the app was loaded using adb install when the phone was plugged in with usb cable to computer instead of from Google Play store or any other store. On iOS it means the app was installed by xcode.

Comment: @djabi what about Baidu Store ? what it will return ?

Comment: It will return the package name of the Baidu Store app. I don't know what it is but if you have device with Baidu Store on it you can look up the app package. "com.android.vending" is the package name of Google Play Store app.

Comment: @djabi, do you know if testflight installs on ios will be reported as manual or iTunes? I could not find reference for this anywhere.