# Different values of 'user_dim.app_info.app_store' for one user (app_instance_id) in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have question about users who have logged to Firebase analytics more than one 'app_store' name and one of them is 'com.android.vending' like below:

```
Row app_instance_id                     count   app_store    
28  b3771637cc00844e4b7e813200b910c7    2       com.android.vending  
                                                manual_install   
29  36b611ff86e084026bc8c92978ef7fd5    2       com.android.vending  
                                                manual_install   
30  9f7225e86c099dd2bf7d3628ed7c7b46    2       com.android.vending  
                                            com.google.android.packageinstaller  
31  7000abdb2c6730364c2aa59cf362052d    2       com.android.vending  
                                            com.google.android.packageinstaller  
32  4daad1804a71feb0b9f4a225ceaa9433    2       com.android.vending  
                                            com.google.android.packageinstaller  
33  89e2def5113564ee5d7cfdea6f857d5d    2       com.android.vending  
                                            com.google.android.packageinstaller
```

Did they 'sideloaded' app manually or are they valid users from Google Play Store?

Comment: [Where is the value of the "app_store" in the Firebase come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327588/where-is-the-value-of-the-app-store-in-the-firebase-come-from)

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327588/where-is-the-value-of-the-app-store-in-the-firebase-come-from 'On Android the package of the app that installed the current app is reported by the getInstallerPackageName method provided by the PackageManager.'

Answer (score 0):

`manual_install` are sideloads, `com.android.vending` is google play